# Direct Oracle Access для Delphi XE

Tags: oracle, delphi, компоненты

1. Cуществует ли компонент `doa` для `Delphi XE`?
2. Если да, где скачать?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по оффсайту http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphioci/

Обновление последнее 2009 годом датировалось, о XE тогда еще не знали :)

а в чем у Вас проблема?

Comment: Собственно, нужно перевести проект на новую версию делфи. Решил использовать Rad Studio XE, точнее не решил а сказали сверху:). Этот проект использует данный компонент. Вот и вся проблема.

Comment: Кстати, а как же версия DOA 4.1.2.2. Нашел что эта версия именно на XE

Comment: нашел ссылку!!! Вот Ловите кому надо
http://depositfiles.com/ru/files/6ld3w5p8p